# Balancing the chemical equations in the next line

Tags: equations, mhchem

There should be a way to align the coefficients or oxidation numbers with the molecules and elements using just `mhchem`, but it escapes me. I did some googling for balancing mhchem equations but found nothing of the like.

This is close to what I am trying to achieve, except that I need to move 5 under Arsenic, 2 under Sulfur on the left, and 3 under Arsenic, 0 under Sulfur on the right.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\ce{H3As^{5+}O4 + H2S^{2-} &-> H3As^{3+}O3 + S^0 + H2O}\\
\ce{5 - 2 &-> 3 + 0}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using `chemformula` instead of `mhchem` (the current version of which is `4`, BTW) in combination with `chemmacros`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\chemsetup{
  formula = {chemformula} ,
  modules = {redox} ,
  redox/pos = top
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \ch[name-format=\centering]{
    H3 !($5$)( "\ox{5,As}" ) O4 !($-$)( + ) H2 !(2)( "\ox{-2,S}" )
    !( -> )( -> )
    H3 !($3$)( "\ox{3,As}" ) O3 !($+$)( + ) !(0)( "\ox{0,S}" ) + H2O
  }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: far better than my answer (+1)!, which now after upgrading of `MikTeX` doesn't work anymore :-( ...

Answer (score 1):

See, if the following solution is what you looking for:

[image]

This is obtained by use of tabular environment with some manual adjustment:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{ccc ccc ccc}
\ce{H3} &\ce{As} &\ce{^{5+}O4 + H2} &\ce{S} &\ce{^{2-} -> H3} &\ce{As} &^{3+}O3 + & \ce{S} & \ce{^0 + H2O}\\
        &    5   &   $~\quad -$     & 2     &\ce{->}          &     3  & $+$      &  0     &
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the first line, you could write ` &` directly into one long `\ce`

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Zarkos answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351665/73371):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % math-mode version of "c" column type
\begin{tabular}{CCCCCCCCC}
\ce{H3As^{+V}O4 &+& H2S^{-II} &    -> & H3As^{+III}O3 &+& S^{\pm0} &+& H2O}\\
    5           &-& 2         &\ce{->}& 3             &+& 0        &
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered output]